# Issue with resolving object based on specific type in Unity container

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to resolve type received in an object using the Unity container, based on `string` or `int` which I will be receiving in this object. So that I can implement logic based on the type. Below is what I tried to register in Unity, but when using  `typeof()` in the Unity container, I'm getting an error, stating that I'm unable to register this.

Is there anyway I can do this using unity?

```
public interface IActionResolver
{
    void Resolve(object item);
}

public class StringResolver : IActionResolver
{
    public void Resolve(object item)
    {
    }
}

public class IntResolver : IActionResolver
{
    public void Resolve(object item)
    {
    }
}
```

And in Unity I tried to register like this..

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IActionResolver, StringResolver>(typeof(string));
unityContainer.RegisterType<IActionResolver, IntResolver>(typeof(int));
```

Comment: Please add the exception message and the stack trace that Unity throws and explain more clearly what the problem is you are trying to solve. As it stands, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Getting this compile time error - 
"cannot convert from 'System.Type' to "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember"

Comment: As i mentioned i mentioned above I will receive either string or int type in an object.Here am trying to add a resolver by setting that type in unity container, so that during runtime when i get this object which contains either string or int i will invoke this this resolve() method of IActionResolver which will execute StringResolver or IntResolver. Hope i didn't confuse

Answer (score 0):

You want to *name* your registrations (with a string as name, not a type):

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IActionResolver, IntResolver>(typeof(int).FullName);
```

and

```
IActionResolver GetResolver( object x )
{
    return unityContainer.Resolve<IActionResolver>( x.GetType().FullName );
}
```